# How to remotely deploy multiple PowerShell cmdlets/scripts to multiple remote devices?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use a single host server to maintain a PowerShell script, with global variables, that can be interpreted and ran on several other devices in the network cluster.

On the main host I'd like to specifically be able to maintain a list of variables for IP addresses of each other device that I want to run the scripts against, but then ***how*** I want to run the script is something I'm having a hard time determining. There are several things I need to do to each other machine in the cluster (change the computer name, modify the time zone and time, configure the network adapters.... there's a decent list of stuff). The commandlets to do the functions on the individual machines is no problem... I have all of that written out and tested. I just don't what my options are for where that script is stored. Preferably, I think I'd like to declare all of the variables for everything that needs to be done on all machines, at the top of the file on the main host. Then I would like to break down everything that needs to be done to each host on the same file, on the main host. I know it will get a little messy, but that would make maintaining the cmdlets for each device much easier, especially when it comes to testing and making changes. Am I trying to do the impossible here??

I learned about using ENABLE-PSSESSION as well as INVOKE-COMMAND, but each seem to have their own challenges. With Enable-PSSession I cannot seem to find a way to wait for the script to connect to each host before it moves on to the next line. I've tried piping in Out-Null, as well as adding a Start-Sleep line. I don't want to have to manually connect to each host and then manually run the list of commands against each host. Invoke-Command doesn't seem to let me break out the SCRIPTBLOCK section into multiple lines.

Is there any suggestion for the best method of accomplishing the desire to run the script from the main host, that performs all of my cmdlets on multiple machines, without any additional human interaction??

Thanks so much!!

-Andrew

EDIT: I found that I ***can*** break the ScriptBlock line (contrary to what I thought didn't work yesterday). Here is basically what I'm trying to accomplish, though of course the below does not work when calling the variables from the top of the file:

```
#Edit These Variables
$NewName_Server2 = "Server2"
$NewName_Server3 = "Server3"
$NewName_Server4 = "Server4"

$IPAddress_Server2 = "10.10.10.2"
$IPAddress_Server3 = "10.10.10.3"
$IPAddress_Server4 = "10.10.10.4"

$TimeZone = "US Eastern Standard Time"


#Do Not Edit These Variables  
$Server2 = "192.168.1.2"
$Server3 = "192.168.1.3"
$Server4 = "192.168.1.4"


#Configure Server 2
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server2 -ArgumentList $local -ScriptBlock {
     Rename-Computer -NewName $NewName_Server2
     New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Wired Ethernet Connection" -IPv4Address $IPAddress_Server2
     Set-TimeZone -ID $TimeZone
     Restart-Computer -Force
}

#Configure Server 3
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server3 -ArgumentList $local -ScriptBlock {
     Rename-Computer -NewName $NewName_Server3
     New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Wired Ethernet Connection" -IPv4Address $IPAddress_Server3
     Set-TimeZone -ID $TimeZone
     Restart-Computer -Force
}

#Configure Server 4
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server3 -ArgumentList $local -ScriptBlock {
     Rename-Computer -NewName $NewName_Server3
     New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Wired Ethernet Connection" -IPv4Address $IPAddress_Server4
     Set-TimeZone -ID $TimeZone
     Restart-Computer -Force
}
```

Comment: As you've found, PowerShell already supports remoting natively, and it sounds more like you just need to learn how to parameterize your scripts correctly. Can you share the actual code (or an equivalent sample)  that you're talking about?

Comment: Thanks so much Mathias, yes you said it better than I did :)

I went ahead and just updated the initial post with an example of what I think I'm trying to do. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd love to see this edited down to a very simple question around what's working and not, as opposed to the large paragraphs above.  Could be a good first question now, with the code sample.

Comment: This is wayyyy too verbose.  Could you trim the fat a bit?  I think your question is "How do I run a script on a group of computers, one at a time?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the using scope to access local variables.  I don't know what $local is.  Nice try.

```
$a = 'hi'
invoke-command comp001,comp002 { $using:a }

hi
hi
```

The other way is using a param, not well documented.  Passing arrays is more tricky.

```
invoke-command comp001,comp002 { param($b) $b } -args $a
```

Comment: Thanks so much js2010.... that first method was very straight-forward and worked like a charm! I appreciate the help a ton!!!

Comment: Hi JS, sorry, I didn't know to use that.... I had gone to give you an upvote and it said I didn't have enough reputation, but now I see the checkmark and was able to mark it as the right answer. Thanks again! :)